# Optaplanner VRP incremental score - tour length

Tags: optaplanner

I want to create incremental score calculation for VRP to minimalize cost, where cost is the variable cost of the vehicle (usd/km) plus the driver cost (usd/h) and I also have a hard constraint which is the total tour length (8h/driver), (for which I added driving speed parameter to all vehicle and also driver usd/h).
I've already implemented it in easy score calculation, but with big dataset it has to run lot more then I want, so I tried the incremental way.

I have tried to simply insert additional lines to the original incremental score calculation, but it seems to fail.
As I read other sources and i think the problem may comes from the update sequence of previousStandstill, vehicle and nextCustomer. So when it updates previousStandstill the customers sometimes doesn't have a vehicle added yet, so i can't pair the driving time (distance from previousStandstill / driving speed) to a given vehicle.

I have already checked that the Customer domain has the @PlanningEntity  annotation and the getVehicle getter has the @AnchorShadowVariable annotation.

I really got stuck here. Any help would be appreciated.

Update:
I've added some code, to the incrementalScore -> insertPreviousStandstill to get the vehicle of the previousStandstill:

```
        Vehicle vehicle = null;
        Vehicle vehicle2 = null;
        Standstill previousStandstill2 = customer.getPreviousStandstill();
        while (vehicle == null) {
            if (previousStandstill2 instanceof Vehicle) {
                vehicle = previousStandstill2.getVehicle();
            } else {
                Customer customer2 = (Customer) previousStandstill2;
                vehicle2 = customer2.getVehicle();
                if (vehicle2 == null) {
                    previousStandstill2 = customer2.getPreviousStandstill();
                } else {
                    vehicle = vehicle2;
                }
            }
        }
        Long vehicle_varcost = vehicle.getVarCost();
        softScore -= customer.getDistanceFromPreviousStandstill() * vehicle_varcost / 1000;
```

(also added vehicle_varcost for all before and after change code)
It works fine until Construction Heuristic (i get the same result with EasyScore), but if fails afterwards.

Comment: JavaIncrementalScoreCalculation with Shadow variables can drive a (wo)man insane, because the "before" calls happen too late (and it's impossible to get them sooner). This is the main reason why ConstraintStreams (the solution here) will still be slower than JavaIncrementalScoreCalculation.

Comment: Thanks @GeoffreyDeSmet!
I had some time at the weekend and bypassed the problem with a <Customer, Vehicle> hash map, which store the lastest calculated previousStandstill vehicle (maybe not the cleanest method, but work well).
I had run several tests and luckly the performance of the code didn't decreased (maybe some percent).